# How to get TestServer to return a client that follows redirects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing, dotnet-httpclient

I have some integration tests that used the `WebApplicationFactory` to return an HTTP client that would follow redirects to test my API as outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#test-a-secure-endpoint).

I've had to switch my tests to use the [TestServer](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/07/01/testserver.aspx). The client that it creates with `CreateClient()` does not follow redirects causing my tests to break. There does not seem to be a way for the `TestServer` to be configured to create a redirect following client.

Is there a way?

Comment: Check the source code here and see if there is anything you can use https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c95ee2b051814b787b07f55ff224d03d550aafeb/src/Middleware/Rewrite/test/MiddlewareTests.cs#L40